# Is it possible to change the Twilio Browser Client ringtone?

Tags: browser, client, twilio, ringtone

I did not find it in Twilio documentation that I can change it.

Does anyone has a solution to this problem?

Perhaps it is possible to replace the mp3 file that is downloaded to the browser and used as a ringtone.

I need this, because my clients are somewhat annoyed by the default ringtone of Twilio browser client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to change default incoming ringtone with some workaround.

Following Twilio client API: https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/device#sounds
you can disable incoming ringtone calling Twilio.Device.sounds.incoming(false). Then you will need to hookup to event Twilio.Device.incoming and manually start you ringtone and hookup to other events to stop playing music when call is answered/cancelled.

Answer (score 4):

Twilio Customer Support  here, its not possible to change the ringtone at this time however you could use  and have a recording of the ring tone you need until the other leg of the call has a status of 'answered'

In the meantime I have added this as a feature request, though I cannot give a firm estimation as to when it might be implemented.

Any further questions ping help@twilio.com

Comment: Thanks Tom, but I did not understand this part: "however you could use and have a recording of the ring tone you need until the other leg of the call has a status of 'answered'. 
I can have a recording of a ringtone. But how can I use it to replace the default ring tone. 
Just to make sure - the ringtone here is the sound that is played in the _browser_, until the party answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to change incoming call ringtone, You can add this code it's working for me also

first add ringtone url like this

```
 var audio = new Audio('/app-assets/audio/Ringback.wav');
```

than add this code when call was coming

```
audio.loop = true;
audio.play();
```

and on answer or reject you can stop ring

```
audio.pause();
audio.currentTime = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE AS OF AUGUST 2020**

Twilio now supports a way to set the ringtone of an outgoing call.  So when a call is made, a specific wav file is played.

It is done with a callback.  So first, here is the callback that Twilio makes to get the URL of the ringtone. Note that they call it a "Wait Tone", not a "RingTone". Note that in this example, I get the ringtone from the database.

```
    [HttpGet("WaitTone")]
    public async Task<TwiMLResult> WaitTone()
    {
        string activeRingtone = await _ringToneRepository.GetActiveRingtoneAsync();
        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        if (activeRingtone.Contains("https"))
            response.Play(new Uri(activeRingtone), 0);
        else
            response.Play(new Uri(@Url.Content(activeRingtone)), 0);
        return TwiML(response);

    }
```

Here is the code that sets the Callback.  Note the "waitUrl" and the "waitMethod" below.

```
dial.Conference(friendlyName,
            startConferenceOnEnter: true,
            endConferenceOnExit: true,
            statusCallbackEvent: new List<Conference.EventEnum> { Conference.EventEnum.Join, Conference.EventEnum.Leave, Conference.EventEnum.End },
            statusCallback: new Uri("/api/Conference", UriKind.Relative),
            statusCallbackMethod: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post,
            record: Conference.RecordEnum.RecordFromStart,
            recordingStatusCallbackEvent: new List<Conference.RecordingEventEnum> { Conference.RecordingEventEnum.Completed },
            recordingStatusCallback: new Uri("/api/Conference/ConferenceRecordingCallback", UriKind.Relative),
            recordingStatusCallbackMethod: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post,
            waitUrl: new Uri("/api/Conference/WaitTone", uriKind: UriKind.Relative),
            waitMethod: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Get
            );
```

[Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-waitUrl)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to change the incoming call ringtone using the `sounds` property when initialising the [Twilio.device](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device#twilio-device), e.g.:

```js
device = new Twilio.Device(token, {
  ...
  sounds: {"incoming": "https://my.website.com/incoming-ringtone.mp3"}
});
```

More information on all the possible value for `sounds` can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device#available-sound-properties)