# Is it possible to change dialing tone?

Tags: twilio

I want to change the standard dialing tone and can not find if it is possible in the twilio documentation.

In the web client (Flash or HTML5) is it possible to upload a custom media file to play while a callee is being dialed?

Comment: It seems not to be possible using the twilio-API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900057/is-it-possible-to-change-the-twilio-browser-client-ringtone

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sounds reference as @gediminasgu explains found here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/device#sounds

> Disable incoming ringtone calling
>   `Twilio.Device.sounds.incoming(false)`. Then you will need to hookup
>   to event `Twilio.Device.incoming` and manually start the  ringtone and
>   hookup to other events to stop playing music when call is
>   answered/cancelled.