# Twilio Voice - how to change incoming call tone with Twilio Functions

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-functions

I have an Australian Twilio number but when people call, they hear a very different sounding ring tone to what you normally hear when calling Australian phones. How do I change this in this section of Functions:

```
    const dial = twiml.dial(
      {
        action: '/handle-call',
        method: 'POST',
        timeout: 20
      }
    );
    dial.sip('me@example.sip.us1.twilio.com');
```

**Edit**: I've tried adding this to the function but I get a 500 error whenever someone tries calling (I've also enabled AUTH_TOKEN in context in the configuration settings).

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const device = new Twilio.twiml.Device();
    device.setup(context.AUTH_TOKEN, {
        sounds: {
            incoming: 'http://url-to-sound-file.mp3'
        }
    });
    ...
```

Comment: Do you receive call on Twilio number or make call from Twilio number?

Comment: Both. It's the inbound calls that I want changed - so the ring tone that people who call me hear before I answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900057/is-it-possible-to-change-the-twilio-browser-client-ringtone

Comment: It seems that answer is now deprecated by Twilio. Also, it doesn't explain how to add this to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you note the ringTone attribute?

TwiML™ Voice: 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#ringtone

Also, note the comment:
"Note: ringTone will never be applied to calls to  endpoints."

Comment: I didn't see that, but as it says I can't use it with sip endpoints which is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly with functions but rather with TwiML Bins. Don't see much sense to copy paste from this article.

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024055153-Change-the-Hold-Music-with-Twilio-Flex